# g2o - what's difference between VertexSE3 and VertexSE3Expmap?

Tags: python, g2o

I'm really new to g2o library and I'm struggling to add pose to vertex :(

I used the python version of g2o and this is the code I wrote.

The type error occus in this line: `v_se3.set_estimate(pose)`

```
import g2o
import numpy as np

solver = g2o.BlockSolverSE3(g2o.LinearSolverEigenSE3())
solver = g2o.OptimizationAlgorithmLevenberg(solver)
optimizer = g2o.SparseOptimizer()
optimizer.set_algorithm(solver)

trans = np.zeros(shape=[], dtype=np.float64)
quat = g2o.Quaternion(np.array([1., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=np.float64))
pose = g2o.SE3Quat(quat, trans)

v_se3 = g2o.VertexSE()        
v_se3.set_id(0)
v_se3.set_estimate(pose)         # <- ERROR OCCURS HERE!
optimizer.add_vertex(v_se3)
```

The error says

```
Type error: set_estimate(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self:g2o.BaseVertex_6_Isometry3D, et:g2o.Isometry3d) -> None
```

I found that I can add vertex when I use `v_se3 = g2o.VertexSE3Expmap()` instead of `g2o.VertexSE3()`.

But I'm not sure what `g2o.VertexSE3Expmap()` exactly means.

So these are my questions,

1. Why `VertexSE3()` is not working here?
2. What's difference between `g2o.VertexSE3` and `g2o.VertexSE3Expmap`?
3. What should I do to add vertex with the quaternion (numpy array)?

Thanks

Comment: That is a fair and clear question. Hope somebody could share some wisdom here.

Answer (score 1):

vertexse3 is represented as an Isometry3d, while vertexse3expmap is parameterized internally with a transformation matrix and externally with its exponential map .

So, if you represent pose as g2o.SE3Quat, you shold use vertexse3expmap.

Comment: Would you please explain more about the usage of `VertexSE3` and `VertexSE3Expmap`? Is the expression of rotation the only difference between `VertexSE3` and `VertexSE3Expmap`?